# What is a way to hide weekdays header in ember-power-calendar dropdown?

Tags: ember.js

I am using `ember-power-calendar` addon in my application to avoid `ember-bootstrap date-picker` since it has jQuery widget. 
The calendar works amazingly fine. But I have a requirement where in the weekdays header(sunday, monday ..saturday) needs to be hidden.

```
{{#power-calendar
  center=fixedDummyDate
  selected=fixedDummyDate
  onSelect=(action 'selectDate' value='date') 
  as |calendar|}}
    {{calendar.days}} 
{{/power-calendar}}
```

## Delivered Output

[image: Change From]

## Expected Output

[image: Change to]

Comment: hey why did you remove this as an answer? did not it solve your problem. it is good to makr correct answers and also upvote them!

Comment: @feanor07 Sorry, My bad!! The way I put in the question was wrong. This is how I want my calendar to look like(Image-2) if I had to hide the weekdays header.

Comment: this is not the way to go; please ask a new question once it is properly answered instead of modifying the question and de marking the answers from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I found a way to add css class to the power calendar to hide the weekdays header.

**CSS Style:**

```
.no-weekdays {
   .ember-power-calendar-weekdays {     
       display: none;
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
{{#power-calendar class="no-weekdays"
   selected=abcDate
   onSelect=(action 'selectDate' value='date') 
   as |calendar|}}
   {{calendar.days}}
{{/power-calendar}}
```

Any other way to hide the header?

Comment: thanks this is helpful. but can you ask same in github issue so that we can discuss if this can be a part of library feature

Answer (score 0):

In fact the official guide has a similar example to what you asked. Did you check the examples at the [Basic-customization>days link](https://ember-power-calendar.com/docs/the-days).

That said; let me explain how you would approach the problem. You need to eliminate say Sunday and Monday from the calendar. You need to customize the `days-component` of `power-calendar`. In order to do that; you can pass a component of your own; let's say the name of the custom component is `days-without-monday-sunday`. Then your usage of the `power-calendar` will be:

```
{{#power-calendar
    center=fixedDummyDate
  selected=fixedDummyDate
  onSelect=(action 'selectDate' value='date')
  daysComponent="days-without-monday-sunday"
  as |calendar|}}
    {{calendar.days}} 
{{/power-calendar}}
```

Now; let's think about the custom `days-without-monday-sunday`. We can make reuse of the existing `power-calendar/days` component within the addon. We need to eliminate `Sunday` and `Monday` from the week header rows. So let's define the js file of the component:

```
import Days from 'ember-power-calendar/components/power-calendar/days'

export default Days.extend({
    // eliminate monday and sunday from the weekdays already constructed ad power-calendar-days
    weekdaysWithoutMondayAndSunday: Ember.computed('weekdays', function() {
        return this.get('weekdays').slice(2,7)
    })
  });
```

Let's define the template of the `days-without-monday-sunday`now. We will use the `weekdaysWithoutMondayAndSunday` in the header row and eliminate `Monday` and `Sunday` days from being rendered:

```
<div class="ember-power-calendar-row ember-power-calendar-weekdays">
  {{#each weekdaysWithoutMondayAndSunday as |wdn|}}
    <div class="ember-power-calendar-weekday">{{wdn}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="ember-power-calendar-day-grid" onkeydown={{action "onKeyDown" calendar}}>
  {{#each weeks key='id' as |week|}}
    <div class="ember-power-calendar-row ember-power-calendar-week" data-missing-days={{week.missingDays}}>
      {{#each week.days key='id' as |day|}}
        {{#if (monday-sunday-checker day)}}
          <button type="button"
            data-date="{{day.id}}"
            class="ember-power-calendar-day {{if onSelect 'ember-power-calendar-day--interactive'}} {{if day.isCurrentMonth 'ember-power-calendar-day--current-month' 'ember-power-calendar-day--other-month'}} {{if day.isSelected 'ember-power-calendar-day--selected'}} {{if day.isToday 'ember-power-calendar-day--today'}} {{if day.isFocused 'ember-power-calendar-day--focused'}} {{if day.isRangeStart 'ember-power-calendar-day--range-start'}} {{if day.isRangeEnd 'ember-power-calendar-day--range-end'}}"
            onclick={{action calendar.actions.select day calendar}}
            onfocus={{action 'onFocusDay' day}}
            onblur={{action 'onBlurDay'}}
            disabled={{day.isDisabled}}>
            {{#if hasBlock}}
              {{yield day publicAPI}}
            {{else}}
                {{day.number}}
            {{/if}}
          </button>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Do not get distracted from the complexity of the template; I copied it directly from the addon itself; [see](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-calendar/blob/master/addon/templates/components/power-calendar/days.hbs). The tricky part to eliminate Monday and Sunday is with `{{#if (monday-sunday-checker day)}}`. In order to do that; we can create a custom helper named `monday-sunday-checker`. The implementation of the helper can be:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function mondaySundayChecker(params/*, hash*/) {
  console.log(params[0]) 
  const day = Ember.get(params[0], 'moment').format('dddd')
  return day !== 'Monday' && day !== 'Sunday';
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(mondaySundayChecker);
```

I have created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/84a4311290e71f8fba86d6cca77e3204?openFiles=helpers.monday-sunday-checker.js%2Ctemplates.components.days-without-monday-sunday.hbs) for you to illustrate this in action; but it does not look good due to missing `css` definitions; but it will at least give you an idea. Hope this helps.